# How to collapse sheets query result into a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I have a sheets query that almost does what I want but I need a bit of help to get to the last step.

```
=QUERY(Sales!$A$2:$C,"SELECT B, SUM(C) 
WHERE A='"&B3&"' 
GROUP BY B 
ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC 
LIMIT 3 
LABEL SUM(C) '' 
FORMAT SUM(C) '$##,##0' "
,0)
```

[image]

This gives me the result in C3:D4. What I want is in E3.

I have two goals. First output the data stacked and joined like in cell E3. Second, the ideal solution is an array formula in C3 that does this for all the 'Partners'.

[Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uSljtdjFXdJnwYDESqo8ezvsnora5ViThX_94Xk2-uA/edit?usp=sharing)

As always thanks in advance for the assistance and education!

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is creating a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) in Google Apps Script. To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function GET_TOP_CUSTOMERS(partners) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sales");
  const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  return partners.map(row => row[0]).map(partner => {
    const partnerRows = data.filter(row => row[0] === partner);
    const uniqueCustomers = [...new Set(partnerRows.map(row => row[1]))];
    const topCustomers = uniqueCustomers.map(customer => {
      return [customer, partnerRows.filter(row => row[1] === customer)
        .reduce((acc, current) => {
          return acc + current[2] }, 0)];
    }).sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1]).slice(0, 3);
    return topCustomers.map(customer => customer[0] + "; $" + customer[1].toFixed())
                       .join("\n");
  });
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function like any in-built one. You just have to provide the appropriate range (in this case it would be `B3:B12`), as you can see here:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I thank you for the response but unfortunately I don't know how to modify this so it will work in my real world data where the tabs and the columns are quite different. If anyone can do what I need with a standard calculation I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: @ChrisRosendin if the problem was summing up the different amounts for each customer, I just updated my answer to do just that, in case it might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it. Maybe not the optimal solution because I need to duplicate the calculation, but it does exactly what I need. I've added my solution to the example data.

> =REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(textjoin(" ♦ ",0,
>   QUERY({Sales!$A$2:$A,Sales!$B$2:$B,Sales!$C$2:$C},"SELECT Col2, SUM(Col3) 
>   WHERE Col1='"&B3&"' 
>   GROUP BY Col2 
>   ORDER BY SUM(Col3) DESC 
>   LIMIT 3 
>   LABEL SUM(Col3) '' 
>   FORMAT SUM(Col3) '$##,##0' "
>   ,0)
>   )," ♦ \$"," = \$")," ♦ ",CHAR(10))

[image]